# Trying to use PowerShell to create a URL shortcut on desktop using a variable for the URL

Tags: powershell, variables, url, shortcut

I work in higher ed and we need the computers in each of our 100+ classrooms to have a URL shortcut on the desktop to the room camera's IP address.  I am trying to automate this using a PowerShell script.  I have created a script that has a table, looks up the computer name, looks it up in the table to find the associated IP address, and creates a URL shortcut on the desktop.  Unfortunately, I get an error any time I try to pass the $IP variable to $urlShortcut.TargetPath.  I'm hoping this is an easy fix?  Thanks in advance!

Here is a genericized version of my script.  If I replace `$urlShortcut.TargetPath = $IP` with `$urlShortcut.TargetPath = "https://www.google.com"`, for example, it creates the shortcut to Google.

```
#Create table
$table = @{}
$table.Add('Room 1,'1.1.1.1')
$table.Add('Room 2','1.1.1.2')

#Determine computer name
$CPUName = $env:computername

#Determine IP address based on room
$IP = $table[$CPUName]

#Display IP Address
write-output $IP

#Create shortcut on desktop
$wshShell = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"
$urlShortcut = $wshShell.CreateShortcut(
  (Join-Path $wshShell.SpecialFolders.Item("AllUsersDesktop") "Camera Control.url")
)
$urlShortcut.TargetPath = $IP
$urlShortcut.Save()
```

Comment: The bare string `1.1.1.1` is not a valid path, try `$urlShortcut.TargetPath = "http://$IP/"` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) has provided the crucial pointer:

- Use `"http://$IP/"` instead of just `$IP` when assigning to `$urlShortcut.TargetPath`, given that you want to open a *URL*.

The **command forms that shortcut files support in their `.TargetPath` property are those recognized by the [`ShellExecuteEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) WinAPI function**, which both PowerShell's [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet and `cmd.exe`'s internal `start` command wrap.

Thus, you can *test* commands for shortcut files using `Start-Process`; e.g.:

```bash
# !! WRONG 
# Without a protocol specifier such as http:, the URL isn't recognized.
Start-Process example.org

# OK
Start-Process https://example.org
```

However, what `Start-Process` does *not* do<sup>[1]</sup> - unlike shortcut files and `cmd.exe`'s `start command` - is to expand `cmd.exe`-style environment variable references such as `%windir%`.

Thus, **a *complete* emulation of what a shortcut-file command line will  do, from PowerShell, requires calling `cmd.exe`'s internal `start` command via `cmd /c`**; e.g., to test command line `notepad.exe %windir%\win.ini`:

```bash
cmd /c 'start "" notepad.exe %windir%\win.ini'
```

Note: The `""` argument preceding the command line binds to `start`'s argument for specifying a *window title* for the new process (which only applies to calling *console* applications). Binding this argument allows you to use `"..."`-enclosed executable paths as part of the command line to test.

---

<sup>[1] Owing to the behavior of the .NET API it builds on, [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Diagnostics.Process).</sup>